# Can we generate a data lineage from our DataStage Jobs?

Tags: datastage

We're using IBM DataStage 11.7.1

The metadata asset manager was not used in the Project.

Can we generate a data lineage out of the existing and used jobs (knowing that not 100% can be covered)?  If yes: how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only generate lineage within a job, using DataStage.  That is, you can answer questions "show where data flows to" and "show where data comes from" within the context of the one job.  You can access this functionality by right-click on the stage about which you're interested in asking the question.

Beyond that, you can generate data lineage more formally using the Information Governance Catalog tool.  If you are not using shared metadata resources, and not generating operational metadata when running jobs, then the lineage report will be based on design data only.

If you share the table definitions you use in your jobs into the common metadata repository (from the Repository menu in DataStage Designer), then you will get better lineage results in IGC.  If you generate operational metadata when running your jobs then these operational metadata will also be available in lineage reports.

Don't forget that DataStage jobs are not included in lineage by default. You need to mark at least the jobs of interest as "include for lineage" in the Administration page of IGC.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. So I have to find out, how to configure and use the IGC. I totally forgot about that.